# Update data of MySQL table if there is no changes in data MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to update a table if there is no changes in data, in **SQL Server** it is possible but in MySQL how I can?

**MySQL**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PEOPLE;
CREAte tempORARY  table PEOPLE
(
    _data CHAR(1),
    id int
);

INSERT into PEOPLE
SELECT 'N',1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Y',2 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'N',3 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Y',4;

-- now I want to update it
UPDATE PEOPLE
SET _data = 'A'
WHERE id = 1;
-- 1 row(s) affected

-- now I want to update it again
UPDATE PEOPLE
SET _data = 'A'
WHERE id = 1;
-- 0 row(s) affected
```

I want to update data if there is no changes in data.

**SQL Server**

```
DECLARE @tempORARY  table
(
    _data CHAR(1),
    id int
);

INSERT into @tempORARY 
SELECT 'N',1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Y',2 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'N',3 UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Y',4;

-- now I want to update it
UPDATE @tempORARY 
SET _data = 'A'
WHERE id = 1;
-- 1 row(s) affected

-- now I want to update it again
UPDATE @tempORARY 
SET _data = 'A'
WHERE id = 1;
-- 1 row(s) affected
```

I hope I cleared my question, if you still have doubt, please comment.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you add more info please.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more? *I want to update data if there is no changes in data.* -- how do you know if there is no changes?

Comment: That's the default behaviour of MySQL and I don't think you can change it.

Comment: I am changing SQL Server to MySQL, so I need this

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why you want to do something like that... but how about using the WHERE clause

something like:

```
UPDATE @tempORARY 
SET _data = 'A'
WHERE id = 1 AND _data != 'A';
```

hope this helps

Comment: I want this because it is possible in SQL Server, so I think I could do it in MySQL also